# Passing multiple forms from View to Controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an application that books Guests in hotelrooms. In the HttpGet I pass a ReservationViewModel from my Controller to the View. This VM contains all the reservationdetails and 2 empty Guest objects (or however many). For each Guest object I show a form where the user needs to enter information about the Guest. However when I try to submit it only returns the info of one Guest. I've tried looking for a way to pass an array or multiple guests, but that doesn't seem to be possible, only sending one Guest object with parameters seems to work..

Here is the code for my GET:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit2(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Reservation reservation = resRepo.GetReservationByID(id);
        ReservationVM reservationVM = new ReservationVM(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < reservation.amount_people; i++)
        {
            reservationVM.guests.Add(new Guest());
        }

        foreach(Guest guest in reservationVM.guests)
        {
            guest.name = " ";
            guest.zipcode = " ";
            guest.housenumber = 0;
            guest.suffix = "";
            guest.email = " ";
            guestRepo.AddGuest(guest);
        }
        guestRepo.Save();

        reservationVM.date = (DateTime)reservation.date;
        reservationVM.amount_people = (int)reservation.amount_people;
        reservationVM.ID = reservation.ID;
        reservationVM.room_ID = (int)reservation.room_ID;

        if (reservation == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(reservationVM);
    }
```

And my POST:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit2([Bind(Include = "room_ID,date,amount_people,ID")]Reservation reservation, [Bind(Include = "ID,name,zipcode,housenumber,suffix,email")]Guest guest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            resRepo.UpdateReservation(reservation);
            resRepo.Save();
            guestRepo.UpdateGuest(guest);
            guestRepo.Save();

            Reservation r = new Reservation { ID = reservation.ID };
            db.Reservations.Add(r);
            db.Reservations.Attach(r);

            Guest g = new Guest { ID = guest.ID };
            db.Guests.Add(g);
            db.Guests.Attach(g);

            r.Guests.Add(g);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(reservation);
    }
```

and my form for completion:

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x16Mo.png)

Now I was wondering how to pass all the forminfo to my Controller and use that information to save the Reservation and each Guest, so I can write that to my db.

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried the solution given, but I can't seem to get the Guest information in my database. Problem seems to be that when it reaches the foreach loop to get the guests out of reservationVM it's empty. Tried writing to Debug output whenever it entered the loop but it never does. Here's my code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit2(ReservationVM reservationVM)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Get reservation
            Reservation reservation = resRepo.GetReservationByID(reservationVM.ID);
            //Update values in model 
            reservation.date = reservationVM.date;
            reservation.amount_people = reservationVM.amount_people;
            reservation.ID = reservationVM.ID;
            reservation.room_ID = reservationVM.room_ID;
            //Update to DB and save changes
            resRepo.UpdateReservation(reservation);
            resRepo.Save();

            foreach (Guest guest in reservationVM.guests)
            {
                Guest temp = guestRepo.GetGuestByID(guest.ID);

                temp.name = guest.name;
                temp.zipcode = guest.zipcode;
                temp.housenumber = guest.housenumber;
                temp.suffix = guest.suffix;
                temp.email = guest.email;
                temp.ID = guest.ID;

                guestRepo.UpdateGuest(temp);
                reservation.Guests.Add(temp);
            }
            guestRepo.Save();

            //Reservation r = new Reservation { ID = reservation.ID };
            //db.Reservations.Add(r);
            //db.Reservations.Attach(r);

            //Guest g = new Guest { ID = guest.ID };
            //db.Guests.Add(g);
            //db.Guests.Attach(g);

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(reservationVM);
    }
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow.  I just wanted to say you did a great job on writing your first question--hope you find your answer and enjoy the community!

Comment: @Luuk Pook, Need to see your view!

Comment: yes posted it! it's in the pic

Comment: You missed the `using namespaces` part of the view in the picture. Include the `using namespaces` part

Comment: My bad.. Edited.

Comment: If you need any other code let me know. Didn't want to make my post enormous with all my code

Comment: Well, that way I don't learn right? And don't feel comfortable with that.. Could you try to explain maybe? Then I can try it myself. (:

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `ReservationVM` from view to the post method. So write your post method as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit2(ReservationVM reservationVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Here access the necessary values you need from `reservationVM` and do your necessary stuffs

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(reservation);
}
```

Comment: Oh that seems very easy.. I will try it in a bit. I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get your guest information in you post action, you need to make the guest fields as follow:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.guests.count; i++)
{
   Your editor will be like below 

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.guests[i].ID)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.guests[i].name)
}
```

try making the fields in razor view like the above code .. it’ll work.

Comment: Hey, I still don't have my Guests in the database... here's an example of code
`@for(var i = 0; i < @Model.guests.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.guests[i].ID, "ID:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.guests[i].ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Comment: That code is terrible formatted, hope you can figure out what I did.